# How to properly reference dlls that will be in the GAC using TFS and a Build Agent

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, gac

We are moving to VS2010 and TFS from VS2008.

Presently we have a solution that has a dozen or so projects that are built into DLLs and then put in the GAC as well as 3 website projects in this solution that are built that use these DLLs that are put into the GAC.

In VS2008 we have post build events that use gacutil to register them and this all worked great on local developer machines however it doesn't work with TFS and the Build agents.  I had to remove this post build event.

The issue now is the websites won't build because the DLLs are not in the GAC on the build machine where the agent is doing the building.

I tried referenceing the projects in VS2010 from the websites but this simiply removes the assembly references from the web.configs and then copies the dlls to the bin folder when it's built/published which is not what we want.

These DLLs will be in the GAC in production and the 3 websites all use them so we don't want them in the BIN folders.

We have third party DLLs as well that will go in the GAC that are used in all 3 websites as well.

What is the proper way to get this to work in VS2010 and TFS?

Answer (score 1):

Installing the DLLs into the GAC can be a real pain with version management and deployment. Try creating a "Lib" folder to keep all the third party DLLs. We do this in our work and works fine. This won't be a problem with XCopy deployment as well. 
See [help with TFS and referenced DLLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971377/help-with-tfs-and-referenced-dlls) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

To register a DLL into the GAC you need admin level privileges, which is by default not the case of you Team Build Service account. That's the reason why it fails.

You have then two choices:

1. Put admin privileges to the Build Account for you GACTUtil to succeed.
2. Change your Visual Studio projects that reference the DLLs that were supposed to be in the GAC to a specific location you'll deploy them (e.g a ThirdParties folder for third parties DLL, and another one for your own DLLs) in debug/testing configurations, keep the GAC reference in release.

Some people will tell you that 1. sucks because you're not supposed to give admin level to the account, because it's bad.

Some people will tell you that 2. sucks because things get over complicated and that you won't test things the way they actually ship.

My advice is go for 1. because:
 - It's easy to do
 - You don't break your current architecture
 - Admin level to the service won't be that bad a risk, really...