# Error generating pipeline, marks error in a class that comes from an assembly external to the project

Tags: xamarin.ios, continuous-integration, yaml, azure-pipelines

I am configuring my pipeline in a yml file, it works fine already in a version of my old application, but I added a dll, for a new functionality that I need in my application, but now when I run the pipeline again, it gets to the task of doing build error and it marks me, it can't find the references to that assembly I added,
Is there a 'task' that can solve that, or is there a way to make the build operate?
I can't find a solution.

```
# Xamarin.iOS
# Build a Xamarin.iOS project.
# Add steps that install certificates, test, sign, and distribute an app, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/xamarin

trigger:
- development

pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'

variables:
  - name: configuration
    value: 'Release'

steps:
# To manually select a Xamarin SDK version on the Microsoft-hosted macOS agent,
# configure this task with the *Mono* version that is associated with the
# Xamarin SDK version that you need, and set the "enabled" property to true.
# See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=871629

- script: sudo $AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY/scripts/select-xamarin-sdk.sh 5_12_0
  displayName: 'Select the Xamarin SDK version'
  enabled: false

- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  displayName: 'Install an Apple certificate'
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: '$(namecertificate)'
    certPwd: '$(P12password)'
    keychain: 'temp'

- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  displayName: 'Install an Apple provisioning profile'
  inputs:
    provProfileSecureFile: '$(provisionprofile)'


- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'

- task: XamariniOS@2
  inputs:
    solutionFile: '**/*iOS.csproj'
    configuration: '$(configuration)'
    signingIdentity: $(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)
    signingProvisioningProfileID: $(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)
    packageApp: true

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    contents: '**/*.ipa'
    targetFolder: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

This is the error that the pipeline throws in the 'task' where it does the build

```
  Custom/UI/DigimarcScannerViewRenderer.cs(7,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DMSDK' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/runner/runners/2.168.2/work/1/s/HEB.SAG.App/HEB.SAG.App.iOS/HEB.SAG.App.iOS.csproj]
  Custom/UI/DigimarcScannerViewRenderer.cs(26,34): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DMSDetectorViewControllerDelegate' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/runner/runners/2.168.2/work/1/s/HEB.SAG.App/HEB.SAG.App.iOS/HEB.SAG.App.iOS.csproj]
  Custom/UI/DigimarcScannerViewRenderer.cs(44,53): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DMSDetectorViewController' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/runner/runners/2.168.2/work/1/s/HEB.SAG.App/HEB.SAG.App.iOS/HEB.SAG.App.iOS.csproj]
  Custom/UI/DigimarcScannerViewRenderer.cs(44,95): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DMSResolvedContent' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/runner/runners/2.168.2/work/1/s/HEB.SAG.App/HEB.SAG.App.iOS/HEB.SAG.App.iOS.csproj]
  Custom/UI/DigimarcScannerViewRenderer.cs(44,131): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DMSPayload' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/runner/runners/2.168.2/work/1/s/HEB.SAG.App/HEB.SAG.App.iOS/HEB.SAG.App.iOS.csproj]
  Custom/UI/DigimarcScannerViewRenderer.cs(59,61): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DMSDetectorViewController' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/runner/runners/2.168.2/work/1/s/HEB.SAG.App/HEB.SAG.App.iOS/HEB.SAG.App.iOS.csproj]
  Custom/UI/DigimarcScannerViewRenderer.cs(59,103): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DMSReaderResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/runner/runners/2.168.2/work/1/s/HEB.SAG.App/HEB.SAG.App.iOS/HEB.SAG.App.iOS.csproj]
  Custom/UI/DigimarcScannerViewRenderer.cs(59,25): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DMSPayload' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/runner/runners/2.168.2/work/1/s/HEB.SAG.App/HEB.SAG.App.iOS/HEB.SAG.App.iOS.csproj]
  Custom/UI/DigimarcScannerViewRenderer.cs(64,46): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DMSResolvedContentItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/runner/runners/2.168.2/work/1/s/HEB.SAG.App/HEB.SAG.App.iOS/HEB.SAG.App.iOS.csproj]
  Custom/UI/DigimarcScannerViewRenderer.cs(28,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DMSResolvedContentItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/runner/runners/2.168.2/work/1/s/HEB.SAG.App/HEB.SAG.App.iOS/HEB.SAG.App.iOS.csproj]
  Custom/UI/DigimarcScannerViewRenderer.cs(223,35): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DMSResolvedContentItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/runner/runners/2.168.2/work/1/s/HEB.SAG.App/HEB.SAG.App.iOS/HEB.SAG.App.iOS.csproj]
  Custom/UI/DigimarcScannerViewRenderer.cs(82,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DMSDetectorViewController' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/runner/runners/2.168.2/work/1/s/HEB.SAG.App/HEB.SAG.App.iOS/HEB.SAG.App.iOS.csproj]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error generating pipeline, marks error in a class that comes from an assembly external to the project

That because the `dll` files are ignored by `.gitignore`/`.tfignore` by default.

When we add the dll file to the project in the local and submit/push it to repo, the dll file will be ignored. So, that the dll file will be missing in the repo.

That the reason why you got the error missing an assembly reference.

To resolve this issue, the directly **workaround** is add that `dll` file into the source control and submit it to the repo.

Check [this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971377/tfs-and-referenced-dlls) for some details.

On the other hand, you could also create a nuget package for that `dll` file, and publish it to the artifact feed, so that we could manage this `dll` file by nuget.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent answer, it helped me a lot to fix the error, indeed it was the gitignore, which was denying reading the dll files. I will mark it as the correct answer